# How to use v-for in SweetAlert2 html output

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, sweetalert2

I'm trying to show the following template in an alert with `vue-sweetalert2`:

```
<input v-model="name" class="swal2-input">

<select v-model="parent" name="parent" class="form-control">
  <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="category.id">
    {{category.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I do not have any problem in a normal template, but I don't know how to use this in [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io).

I tried this code:

```
this.$swal({
  text: 'edit child',
  html:
   '<input v-model="name" class="swal2-input">' +
   `<select v-model="parent" name="parent" class="form-control">
      <option value="">nothing</option>
      <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="category.id">
        {{category.name}}
      </option>
    </select>`,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'edit',
  cancelButtonText: 'cancel',
  showCloseButton: true,
})
```

but it shows me nothing.

Comment: where are you putting   this.$swal( ...?

Comment: In my components I haven’t any problem with normal swal()

Comment: did you get errors?

Comment: No but its just show me {{caregory.name}}

Comment: your sweatalert content is out of Vue scope

Comment: I wrote this into a components method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181628/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-mahdi-mirhendi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the HTML passed to SweetAlert2 is not handled by Vue, the template mechanisms (including `v-for` and `v-model`) would not be available, so you would have to manually create the template with JavaScript. Specifically, you would replace:

```
html: `<input v-model="name" class="swal2-input">
<select v-model="parent" name="parent" class="form-control">
  <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="category.id">{{category.name}}</option> ...`
```

with:

```
html: `<input id="my-input" value="${this.name}" class="swal2-input">
<select id="my-select" value="${this.parent}" name="parent" class="form-control">
  ${this.categories.map(cat => `<option value="${cat.id}">${cat.name}</option>`)} ...`
```

Note the `<input>` and `<select>` were given IDs so that we can [fetch the values](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#multiple-inputs) on "pre-confirmation" of the alert:

```
const {value} = this.$swal({
  preConfirm: () => [
    document.getElementById("my-input").value,
    document.getElementById("my-select").value
  ]
});
console.log(value[0]); // value of my-input
console.log(value[1]); // value of my-select
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m82qqprkl)

Comment: its give me Error on  ${this.categories.map(cat => `<option value="${cat.id}">${cat.name}</option>`)}

Comment: i cant use ${} in switalert html Output

Comment: It needs to be inside a template literal string, which you're already using (as shown in the question). Can you edit the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m82qqprkl) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MahdiMirhendi No problem :)